# Set specific application volume in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I have been trying to use `tell application "Google Chrome" to set sound volume to 5` but it gives me `error "The variable volume is not defined." number -2753 from "volume"`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome doesn't have an application-specific volume setting. You can set the volume for your system with `set volume output volume 50`, where you can use any integer from 0 to 100.